# How to apply AngularJS ng-class based on condition?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to implement AngularJS ng-class if condition is true how can achieve this task using below code. I am new to AngularJS Any help will be appreciated.

So far tried code....

main.html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
    ng-disabled="disableSubmitButton" 
    ng-class="{disableSaveCls:disableSubmitButton}" 
    ng-click="submitClicked()">Submit</button>
```

mainCtrl.js

```
 if (PromiseObj.data.StatusLookUpCode === 'COMPLIANCE') {
            $scope.disableSubmitButton = true;
            };
```

Comment: ng-class="{'disableSaveCls':disableSubmitButton}"

Comment: You forgot to enclose the class name in quotes that should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `''` in the class name

Try like this

```
ng-class="{'disableSaveCls':disableSubmitButton}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://embed.plnkr.co/q9swhbwSDujVTakY4p2S/)

what you are doing is correct, but you should apply class like this,

```
ng-class="{'disableSaveCls':disableSubmitButton}"
```

within single quotes